# 2 Javascript Timeouts occur simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 Javascript Timeouts which should make an animation, but the happen simultaneously, even if they have as timeout 1s.

JavaScript:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    let filter = document.querySelector('.filter');
    let body = document.querySelector('body');


    setTimeout(moveRight, 1000);
    setTimeout(scaleRotate, 1000);


    function moveRight() {
        filter.style.marginLeft="10%";
        body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
    function scaleRotate() {
        let deg = 90;
        filter.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
        filter.style.width = "100vh";
    }
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <div class="header-text ml-5">
            <h2 class="font-weight-bold">Andrei Bunea</h2>
            <h3 class="mt-3">full stack developer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You gave them both the same delay. Consider changing the delay of the second `setTimeout` to 2000.

Comment: Thanks, I tought they will happen one after one after another .

Comment: Set timeout doesnt mean "stop execution" it means schedule execution of this function T milliseconds from now. So both are scheduled to occur 1000 milliseconds from now. Nest them if you want them to be sequential.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood how it works . Have a great day !

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at using CSS animations.

Comment: I find them a lot harder, I don't know why .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set them similar delay. If you want scaleRotate to work 1 second after moveRight, you can set scaleRotate timer in moveRight timer:

```js
setTimeout(moveRight, 1000);


function moveRight() {
    console.log("moveRight");
    setTimeout(scaleRotate, 1000);
}
function scaleRotate() {
    console.log("scaleRotate");
}
```